# Web2py orderby, limitby

Tags: mongodb, web2py

My database layer (MongoDB):

```
db.define_table('news', 
    Field('title', label='Title'),
    Field('link', label='Link'),
    Field('date', label='Date'),
    Field('summary',label='Summary'))
```

My controller:

```
def news():
    if len(request.args): page=int(request.args[0])
    else: page=0
    items_per_page=5
    limitby=(page*items_per_page,(page+1)*items_per_page+1)
    orderby="~date"
    qset = db(db['news'])
    grid = qset.select(orderby=orderby, limitby=limitby)
    return dict(grid=grid,page=page,items_per_page=items_per_page)
```

My view:

```
<table class="news-stories">
<th>Date</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Summary</th>
{{for i, row in enumerate(grid):}}
{{if i==items_per_page:break}}
<tr>
<td>{{=row.date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")}}</td>
<td><a href="{{=row.link}}" target="_blank">{{=row.title}}</a></td>
<td>{{=row.summary}}</td>
</tr>
{{pass}}
</table>

{{if page:}}
<a href="{{=URL(args=[page-1])}}">previous</a>
{{pass}}

{{if len(grid)>items_per_page:}}
<a href="{{=URL(args=[page+1])}}">next</a>
{{pass}}
```

When I set `orderby="~date"` or `orderby="date desc"`, as in the example above, my dates are not ordered appropriately in desc order; some dates in November come after dates in December (and vice-versa). However, when I set `orderby="date"`, the dates are ordered perfectly in asc order. Am I missing something here?

Dates are inserted as `datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%m/%d/%Y")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
orderby = ~db.news.date
```

See details in the [documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#orderby--groupby--limitby--distinct--having-orderby_on_limitby-left-cache).